# SharePoint 2010 User appears twice in People Picker

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We are in the process of Migating to a new Domain. I have turned off the User Profile Synchronization (with AD, but not the one that syncs the profiles with the User Information List). I have been using "Move-SPUser" to migrate the user accounts to the new domain as we migrate them. So far, it is working "pretty well", but I do have one particular issue that I can't seem to resolve.

I have (only) one specific user that shows up in the People Picker twice (and only for the root Site Collection, the user is a member of another Site Collection and it works correctly, only showing the users new domain account). In the root Site Collection the user shows up twice, once under the old domain and once under the new Domain. I have tried modifying their User Profile directly (in Central Admin). I have used Move-SPUser (several times, even moved them back to the old domain and then back again). No matter what I do, they always show up twice in the People Picker. I assume the reason they are showing up twice is when I look at their accounts in the UserInfo database (only for the root site collection content db). There are two Active (tp_IsActive = 1) accounts for that user. One contains the login for the old domain, the other the new domain (there is another row in the table that is "inactive" (tp_IsActive = 0) that I suppose was "migrated" when I ran the Move-SPUser). The only account that has "tp_Deleted" = 0 (which I assume means it HASN'T been "deleted") is the new domain account. I am to the point were I am considerg actually changing the "tp_Login" to the new domain and setting the tp_IsActive flag to 0 directly in the SQL table. I just don't know what else to do. I have tried using the "Get-SPUser" powershell command to get the user and change it that way, but when I try to get it, I get "you must specify a valid user object or user identity". I can get the account for the new domain just fine, but not the old one. (I assume this has something to do with the "tp_Deleted" field.)

Any help with this is MUCH appreciated!

UPDATE: I think I figured out what has happened here. I just had to move a user back to the old domain. After doing this, I ended up with the same situation as I describe above! (The user has an "Active" account in BOTH domains now, even though I used "Move-SPUser".) I don't remember migrating the other user BACK to the old domain, but at this point, anything is possible....

On a side note, is there a better way to "migrate" users? Unfortunately, we are in a special situation. When we migrate a user, we have to keep their old Domain account as-is (active). This is why I had to disable the AD Profile synchronization. As I said, so far it seems to be working pretty well. Once we get rid of the old domin ENTIRELY, I will set the Profile AD Sync back up to only use the new Domain and get everything cleaned up, completely. I didn't know any other way to "straddle" two domains....